# Circular dependent structs in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, struct, suffix-tree

Heres a simple question, I'm implementing suffix array but I'm stuck here:

```
#define SIZE 150

struct node{
     transition *next[SIZE];   //error here
};

struct transition{
    int left, right;
    node *suffix_link;
};
```

This code won't compile, there's an error in the third line, can anyone help me plz? thanks :D

UPDATE: My bad I forgot to include the first line, sorry it's my first question here :P

Comment: what is `SIZE`?  Did you predeclare `transition`?

Comment: What's the error? You could try moving the definition/declaration of `transition` before `node`.

Comment: is this all the code?
what is the error?

Comment: @birryree that would still give an error, because `node` wouldn't be declared for transition, and you'd still need a forward declaration.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - oh good point - I didn't notice that they were circularly dependent.

Comment: @birryree: Notice that `node` and `transition` have a circular dependency.

Answer (score 8):

You need to forward declare transition:

```
struct transition;  // <-- forward declaration

struct node{
     transition *next[SIZE];
};

struct transition{
    int left, right;
    node *suffix_link;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a forward declaration:

```
struct transition;

struct node
{
    transition *next[SIZE];
};

struct transition
{
   int left, right;
   node *suffix_link;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why forward declaration?**

Because, the complete defintion of *transition* is not yet known to the compiler when you use it.

The same is not required for *node* because it's already been defined when you use it in *transition*.